# Update bit field using MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips

How would one update a specific bit field in the register using MIPS assembly?

For example, if I need to update bits 10 through 15 in register $t1 with a new value. All the other bits should remain as they are.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose `$t0` contains the 6 bit field that you want to move into bits 10-15 of `$t1`.

You might consider this approach:

```
li  $t2 0x3F     #bits 0-5 on
sll $t2 $t2 10   #bits 10-15 on
not $t2 $t2      #bits 10-15 off

and $t1 $t1 $t2  #turn off bits 10-15
or  $t1 $t1 $t0  #set bits 10-15
```